# Use same DataTemplate for different types

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

Is it possible to use the same DataTemplate for a defined selection of types, i.e. how to change the following sample code so that the same DataTemplate is used for all listed types?

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ClassA, ClassB, ...}">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label Content="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
      ...
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 10):

This isn't supported by default, but typically I put the contents of the `DataTemplate` in a `UserControl` or another `DataTemplate` (depends on how complex the template is), and just write a 3-line data template for each class item

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label Content="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
      ...
   </StackPanel>
</UserControl >


<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ClassA}">
    <local:MyUserControl />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ClassB}">
    <local:MyUserControl />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ClassC}">
    <local:MyUserControl />
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported out of the box, but it would be possible to do something like this by defining custom MarkupExtension. Similar to x:Type extension.

If here, ClassA, ClassB are deriving from same class you should be able to put the base class name here to refer them all.